# Transit Visa Requirement for Indian at Bangkok DMK

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dmk

I'm from Mumbai, India and will be visiting Vietnam later this year with my wife.

For the return flight, we are planning to book the flight via DMK.

Below is my flight plan.

**Thai AirAsia Flight**

*Ho Chi Minh 21.35pm - Don Mueang 23.05pm*

**Transit Time at DMK - 3h 20min**

**Thai Lion Air**

*Don Mueang 02.25am - Mumbai 05.40am*

I had couple of queries:

a. Do we need a transit visa at DMK ? Will onward ticket to Mumbai, although with a different connecting airline suffice ?

b. Is 3 Hours enough time to collect baggage and check-in for the Lion Air Flight? I'll probably be arriving and departing from Terminal 1.

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transit without visa at DMK airport is only possible when both flight segments are on Thai AirAsia or Thai AirAsia X and booked on the same ticket. If you are on any other carrier, or on separate tickets, you must clear immigration and have a visa.

Indian citizens can get a visa on arrival if there is at least 30 days validity on your passport. You can also [obtain an e-visa in advance](http://www.evisathailand.com/). Because you have to pay in cash for the visa on arrival, you may find it more convenient to obtain the e-visa in advance.

---

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, says in relevant parts:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers
>   transiting through Bangkok (DMK) arriving on Thai AirAsia (FD) or Thai
>   AirAsia X (XJ) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight on Thai
>   AirAsia (FD) or Thai AirAsia X (XJ) to a third country within 12
>   hours. The connecting flight must be booked on the same ticket. They
>   must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have
>   documents required for the next destination.
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers traveling    on Angkor Air (K6), Beijing Capital Airlines (JD), Business    Air (8B),
>     Cebu Pacific (5J), Eaststar Jet (ZE), Golden    Myanmar Airlines (Y5),
>     Indigo (6E), Jeju Air (7C), Jet Asia    Airways (JF), Jetstar (JQ),
>     Jetstar Pacific (BL), Jin Air    (LJ), JuneYao Airlines (HO), Lao
>     Central Airlines (LF),    Mandara Airlines (RI), Norwegian Air (DY),
>     Okay Airways    (BK), Orient Thai Airlines (OX), Regent Air (RX),
>     Scoot    (TR), Shandong Airlines (SC), Shanghai Airlines (FM),
>     Shenzhen Airlines (ZH), Siberia Airlines (S7), Sichuan    Airlines
>     (3U), South East Asian Airlines (DG), Spice Jet    (SG), Thai Smile
>     Airlines (WE), Tianjin Airlines (GS),    Trans Aero (UN), Turkmenistan
>     Airlines (T5), T'way Airlines    (TW), Ural Airlines (U6) and VietJet
>     Air (VJ).

While Thai Lion Air (SL) is not listed, TWOV also does not apply, as it is also a low cost carrier and has no transit desk. So you need a visa.

Visa requirements for entry from Timatic:

> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be   valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.
> - When applying for a visa on arrival, normal passports    issued to nationals of India must be valid for a minimum of    30 days from the
>     arrival date.
>
> Visa Issuance:
>
> - E-visas can be obtained before departure at   www.eVisaThailand.com. Passengers must have a printed e-visa
>     confirmation.
> - Nationals of Bhutan, India and Romania with a normal   passport traveling as tourists can obtain a visa on arrival   at Bangkok (BKK
>     and DMK), Chiang Mai (CNX), Chiang Rai   (CEI), Hat Yai (HDY), Krabi
>     (KBV), Phuket (HKT), Samui Int'l   (USM), Sukhothai Int'l (THS), Surat
>     Thani (URT) and Utapao   (UTP) for a maximum stay of 15 days. They
>     must have a   confirmed return/onward ticket with a departure within
>     15   days from arrival date, a proof of accommodation, 1 recent
>     passport photo and at least THB 10,000.- per person (or THB   20,000.-
>     per family). Their passport must contain at least 1   unused visa page
>     and the visa fee must be paid in cash only   and in THB.

---

As for separate tickets, I am not that familiar with DMK, but I wouldn't even think of booking separate tickets without at least four hours between them, anywhere in the world. I have a fairly low appetite for that kind of risk. Since you're getting a visa anyway, you can go out into the city and stay overnight if you wish, which would virtually eliminate any risk of missing your connection.